# Chrome Proxy Settings Resetting

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

In recent weeks Google Chrome is "self-activating" Proxy Server setting.  It's so annoying sitting with a "hung" screen, then having to go into settings, untick the "use proxy server" setting and refresh everything.
Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Windows.  Chrome takes its proxy settings from the system settings.  It may be that another browser is setting your proxy back on.  As likely as not Internet Explorer.  Your problems may have started when the other browser was updated.  Check all installed browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the Operating System's proxy settings by default. For example, if you have any proxy server set up in Windows 10

[image: Windows proxy settings]

Chrome will be using this settings.

In Windows, the settings might be set in another location: Internet Properties, which is usually accessed from Internet Explorer. If you go to Chrome's settings and click on `Open proxy settings`

[image: Chrome proxy settings]

you will be brought to Internet Options -> LAN Settings

[image: Internet Options]

Note that the OS settings may be changed in the background by other applications such as a VPN application.

### Chrome Extensions

There may be Chrome extensions that changes the proxy settings. Check that you do not have any extension installed that changes Chrome's proxy settings

[image: Chrome Proxy Extensions]

### Environment variable

Chrome also picks up proxy Environment Variables from your operating system. On Linux and macOS, the are

```
http_proxy
https_proxy
all_proxy
socks_proxy
```

### Start Chrome with Proxy settings

Finally, the sure-fire way to get Chrome to use a specific proxy setting is to use the `--proxy-server` flag. For example

```
chrome.exe --proxy-server="socks://127.0.0.1:9051"
```

[Chromium documentation on how to use command line flag](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags).